# Make custom task who returns boolean in Gradle

Tags: build, task, gradle

I want to ask how I can make a custom task in gradle for continious build, which do something and returns boolean

```
class MyTask extends DefaultTask {
    @InputFile
    File first

    @InputFile
    File second

    @TaskAction
    boolean check() {
        return ..
    }
}
```

So when I call my task in the build script I want to check if the return value is true or false and to do something. Is this poslible to be done and if yes how if not how to do it another way?

```
task myCheckTAsk(type: MyTask) {
    ...???
}
```

I want to put my logic in separate groovy class because my build.gradle file will become very long and hard to read.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Task actions can't return a value, but they can assign a value to a property of the task, and later tasks can read that value. Note that you should never call a task action yourself; it's up to Gradle to do so.

Comment: Why can't I call a task action?  Suppose I want a task in my Android build to increment versionCode?

Comment: Setting a task property doesn't seem to work in Java (via buildSrc). I get a `MissingPropertyException`. It's simple in Groovy, though.